# What are the bubbles on the surface of cooking bacon?

Tags: bacon

As you can see in the picture, this bacon is just about ready to be removed from the heat.

[image: bubbly bacon]

**Just what are those bubbles/foam(?) on the surface of the bacon?**

*Note: this is fresh bacon from a butcher-- not processed or packaged-- if that makes a difference.*

Comment: Wow, you must like your bacon really crispy.

Comment: Haha it's not as mega-crispy as it may appear...

Comment: juice vaporizes and being encapsulated in fat-layered bubbles unti  burst

Comment: Crispy is the only way to eat bacon!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's just steam and hot air bubbling in the layer of fat/grease that's all over the bacon.

Comment: yep it's boiling water, and the oil in the pan is rendered fat. the same way whale blubber was rendered into lamp oil. Just an interesting factotem