# Why are oil bubbles when cooking bacon only around the bacon?

Tags: bacon

When bacon cooks it is in oil.
The oil does not bubble anywhere except the edges of the bacon.
Why?

Comment: Also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/what-are-the-bubbles-on-the-surface-of-cooking-bacon?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

The bacon has some moisture, while cooking the water that gets out of the bacon reacts explosively with hot oil (as it quickly turns to steam) and causes the oil to bubble. Similarly other substances when cooked change phase quickly and turn to gas forming the bubbles and splashing.

See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21864/why-does-hot-oil-explode-when-pouring-water-on-it) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say "explosively". When you're frying bacon, it's mostly just that steam comes out, forms bubbles, and they quickly reach the air and pop. The splatter (if you're frying it hot enough) is just from bubbles bursting.

Comment: the splatter is from a small pocket of water being converted to steam nearly instantly, it is indeed an explosion. Sometimes water doesn't turn to steam right away, but becomes superheated in liquid form, but when it does decide to turn to gas, it can happen all at once....This is why popcorn pops the way it does.